# Change an existing file's permissions using cmake

Tags: file, cmake, installation

I have a component that I install onto my Linux distro using `cmake`.  There is a file on my machine on which I'd like to change permissions - I want to make it non-executable.

My use case is this:

There is a directory that contains several files.  A process periodically executes all of the files in that directory if they are executable.  When I install my program, I would like to make one of those files non-executable and drop my executable file(s) in that directory to be used by the system instead.

I found the [file manipulation section in the cmake docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#filesystem) but the `FILE_PERMISSIONS` feature requires that I include a `COPY` or `INSTALL` of a file in order to use it.

How does one update file permissions on a file that already exists on the system?  I haven't tried anything yet because I don't see any support for such a feature.

Honestly, this seems a little beyond `cmake`'s reach (manipulating files outside of my project) so if there is an alternative way to solve this cleanly, I'm open to ideas.  I'd like it to be tied to my existing application's installation procedure (hence my desire to utilize `cmake`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a shell script that changes permissions and run it during installation using `install(CODE "execute_process(COMMAND \"yourscript.sh\")"`.

Comment: I ended up going a different route (added it to my kickstart) but this is a good solution to the problem presented.  Thanks.